# Proper offloading of certificate when using DNS

Tags: kubernetes

I am using kubernetes. I have hosted a POD on a cluster. It works well with https and I get the right certificates. I map the IP address to DNS. If I try to access the DNS name over https, I get IP address's certificate. I need to get the new  DNS certificate. I use Ingress, service and a pod. From which should I offload certificate in this case. Should I do configure my certificate in Ingress or Service or POD?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, it belongs on the Ingress entity.

Here are a couple of examples where the Certificates are obtained and managed quite differently, but both use the same pattern of attaching the certificate to the Ingress entity via Secrets:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl.  In this example the secrets are explicitly configured with the Cert and Key, these secrets are then attached to the Ingress entity via its tls attribute:

https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/blob/master/docs/tutorials/acme/quick-start/index.rst.  In this example, CertManager is installed, a LetsEncrypt issuer is configured, then the Ingress is just annotated and CertManager will obtain and renew appropriate certificates as required and create and update the secrets accordingly.

Comment: SSL certificates should be offloaded by DNS server or my application?

Comment: By offload, do you mean terminating TLS?  The DNS server is just for resolving host name to IP. Your browser queries DNS, gets in IP address, then sends a connection to that IP address (encrypted in this case).  You aren't going to terminate TLS after DNS query and send the request unencrypted to your browser.  You can terminate TLS at the application, but end up with lots of issues with routing ingress etc because those services can't examine the request path and headers to make decisions on where to forward the request. So you terminate at Ingress, and the internal traffic is unencrypted.

Comment: In ingress, I am using the certificates I have, but I keep getting the original certificates. I have DNS like abc.test.com but certificates returned is that of abc.eng.test.com because the cluster is on .eng.test.com. I don't see my new certificates being picked up.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the cluster is on .eng.test.com".  Did you point .eng.test.com at the master node?  At one of the nodes?  At a LoadBalancer IP address?  Are you the one that configured .eng.test.com?

Comment: Taking a step back, I'd confirm that ingress and dns are working together without tls.  What are you using as an ingress controller?  nginx?  Delete the ingress record.  Go to http://abc.test.com.  Are you getting the default backend?  Or still your app?  If it's your app, abc.test.com isn't correctly pointing to the external IP address of the Ingress Controller's Service.